# What is the best way to get the JSON ABI after deploying a contract with Truffle to Ganache or Kovan?

Tags: solidity, truffle, abi

Remix makes it so easy to get the JSON ABI.

Does anyone have any recommendation on how best to get the JSON ABI after successfully deploying a contract using Truffle without having to leverage Remix?

Answer (score 13):

when you run

```
$ truffle compile
```

truffle creates and saves a json file per contract in `/yourProjectPath/build/contracts`. In this json file you'll find the abi, the bytecode, the topics (if you have any `event` in your smart contract), the function definitions etc (you get the point I guess, I encourage you to spend some time understanding that file - just to get a broad understanding).

personally I use python for my projects. Here is how I automatically load my abi into my scripts for transacting with my contracts (using [web3py](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.py))

```
import json

PATH_TRUFFLE_WK = '/home/myUserName/Projects/myEthereumProjet/'
truffleFile = json.load(open(PATH_TRUFFLE_WK + '/build/contracts/myContractName.json'))

abi = truffleFile['abi']
bytecode = truffleFile['bytecode']
```

You can do the same with your favorite programming language or simply copying-pasting your abi by hand.

Answer (score 3):

@salanfe: Your answer is correct.

There are some [problems](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/685) with the truffle compiler though. I had problems especially with functions that had no input parameters...

Due to this issue I suggest to use [solc](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js) instead:

```
solcjs --abi path/to/your/contract.sol
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [solc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html#using-the-compiler)-compiler directly.

More convenient to use the [Solc docker image](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html#docker):

```bash
docker run \
  -v {smart_contract_location_path}:/src:ro \
  -v {result_abi_location_path}:/build \
  ethereum/solc:0.8.3 \
  --allow-paths /src/node_modules \
  --overwrite \
  -o /build \
  --abi \
  /src/contracts/test.sol
```

Remarks:

- here used hardcoded version of compiler - 0.8.3; consider use the latest stable version - *ethereum/solc:stable*
- compiler provides the next output formats:

```bash
  --ast-compact-json   AST of all source files in a compact JSON format.
  --asm                EVM assembly of the contracts.
  --asm-json           EVM assembly of the contracts in JSON format.
  --opcodes            Opcodes of the contracts.
  --bin                Binary of the contracts in hex.
  --bin-runtime        Binary of the runtime part of the contracts in hex.
  --abi                ABI specification of the contracts.
  --ir                 Intermediate Representation (IR) of all contracts
                       (EXPERIMENTAL).
  --ir-optimized       Optimized intermediate Representation (IR) of all
                       contracts (EXPERIMENTAL).
  --ewasm              Ewasm text representation of all contracts
                       (EXPERIMENTAL).
  --hashes             Function signature hashes of the contracts.
  --userdoc            Natspec user documentation of all contracts.
  --devdoc             Natspec developer documentation of all contracts.
  --metadata           Combined Metadata JSON whose Swarm hash is stored
                       on-chain.
  --storage-layout     Slots, offsets and types of the contract's state
                       variables.
```

---

To avoid import errors like *" File outside of allowed directories"* or *"File not found"* define the 'strict' path to file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "../node_modules/@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Hello is Ownable {
..
}
```

---

To get help run this command:

```bash
docker run ethereum/solc:0.8.3 --help

..
  --base-path path     Use the given path as the root of the source tree
                       instead of the root of the filesystem.
  --allow-paths path(s)
                       Allow a given path for imports. A list of paths can be
                       supplied by separating them with a comma.
  --ignore-missing     Ignore missing files.
..
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Why complicate things with truffle (other dependencies/libraries) instead of using the solc compiler directly (within the official docker container)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple tool that does exactly what @salanfe suggested. It's handy when you have multiple contract definitions:

```
# Install it from npm
$ npm install -g truffle-export-abi

# Run it in your truffle project
$ truffle-export-abi
ABI extracted and output file wrote to: build/ABI.json
```

Github repo: https://github.com/maxme/truffle-export-abi

Answer (score 0):

### For JS

```
> truffle compile
```

Then on the js

```
import ERC20Contract from '../build/contracts/ERC20';
const ERC20Token = new web3.eth.Contract(ERC20Contract.abi, contractAddress)
```